# What is the "customer's user ID"?

Tags: plaid

In the [Preventing duplicate Items article](https://plaid.com/docs/link/duplicate-items/#identifying-existing-duplicate-items), it mentions that you can use a specific combination of fields to determine if there are duplicate items or not. And specifically OAuth institutions, it says the combination of fields are: `customer's user ID` and `institution_id`. I'm confused what the `customer's user ID` is. I'm not familiar with this identifier. Can somebody explain?

Answer (score 2):

The customer's user ID would be a value in your own application's business logic, not part of the Plaid API. In most Plaid use cases, alongside an Item, you would typically store some kind of user id that associates it with a specific user in your system. The logic here is saying that if the same end user in your system has multiple Items with the same institution, they are probably duplicate Items.

Comment: Got it... but couldn't the same user say have one item with an institution which linked their checking account and another item with the same institution but linked their savings account? So what I'm getting at is regardless of if the institution supports OAuth or not, my application logic should always be checking the name/mask/institution_id to determine if the item is a duplicate or not, right?

Comment: The user *could* have multiple Items with different accounts, but it's very unusual. Typically all the accounts they want to use with your app will be on the same Item. Using `institution_id` + user ID for OAuth is recommended because for OAuth institutions, an account mask and account name is not always available from the `onSuccess` callback.

Comment: Oh I was not aware of the fact that for OAuth institutions, the account name/mask could be coming back as empty. Well that's unfortunate then, that there doesn't seem to be a bulletproof way to avoid duplicate items... :(